# How to do something on each third for loop iteration

Tags: javascript

How can i do alert on each third loop iteration
So basically alert ("Some text") on each third iteration, how can i make it?

```
for(var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
   alert("Some text");
}
```

Comment: Either increment `i` by 3... `for(var i = 1; i < 20; i += 3)`... or use the modulo operator... `if (i % 3 === 0) {..}`..

Comment: check when `i % 3` is `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use modulo operator (`%`):

```
for(var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 1) {
        alert("Some text");
    }
}
```