# Trigger after every 3rd time

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger an event after every 3rd time.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    // When i == 3, == 6, == 9 etc.
    if () {
      trigger();
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to represent it in the code, my brain is stuck.

Unless I write: `if i == 3` `if i == 6 etc.`

But I could write millions of these since the i is unlimited.

Comment: Someone even had the exact same question last month: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34660817/218196 .

Comment: i++ is something you see in most generic loops but it can actually be whatever you want it to be. `i++`, `i--`, `i+=#` or `i-=#`. Those last two are coding shorthand for `i=i+#` or `i=i-#`

Comment: No need to downvote smartasses, you get some pleasure out of it?

Answer (score 5):

You could...

- Increment `i` by 3, not 1
- Use `Modulo` to check

So

```
for (i = 0; i < 5000; i=i+3) {
...
}
```

Or

```
for (i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    // When i == 3, == 6, == 9 etc.
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      trigger();
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that those two solutions have different outcomes if there is other stuff in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Use the modulo operator:

```
if (i % 3 === 0) ...
```

condition is true when `i` is 0, 3, 6, ...

Comment: lol you were actually right in calling modulo a function which is why I rolled my edit back. Technically it's the remainder operator that uses the modulo function.